# User Filter for nested OU inside gitlab using RFC 4515

Tags: ldap, gitlab

I am setting up gitlab to have LDAP access.

I would like to give access to 2 seperate OU's  `OU=Users,OU=Dept1,OU=land,DC=my,DC=com`  and `OU=Users,OU=Dept2,OU=land,DC=my,DC=com`  (basically the users of 2 departments.

I believe that I would have to set the base to `OU=land,DC=my,DC=com`  and then use a user_filer (Format: `RFC 4515`)

Probably something of the sort

```
(|(ou=Dept1)(ou=Dept2))
```

How do I extend this to specify only for the USERS within those ou's? Thanks

Note:

When I use the Filter: `(objectClass=user)`I am given access

however if i change it to any of the following I am refused access

```
(&(objectClass=user)(ou=Users))
(&(objectClass=user)(ou=Dept1))
(&(objectClass=user)(ou=Users,ou=Dept1,ou=land))
(&(objectClass=user)(ou=Users,ou=Dept1,ou=land,dc=my,dc=com))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add an objectClass constraint to the filter to limit it only to users , say (&(objectClass=Person))

Comment: objectClass is working however the remaining part isn't. (updated answer)

Comment: You can't include Containers (OU) in your filter unless your LDAP server supports extensible match filter. In which case you could use (&(ou:dn=Dept1)(objectClass=user)). Check if if it works. The other option is to pint your bases to OU=Users,OU=Dept1,OU=land,DC=my,DC=com and OU=Users,OU=Dept2,OU=land,DC=my,DC=com   and filter with (objectClasss=user)

Comment: Which of the two options worked ? Extensible match filter or the other one ?